# Display checkbox data

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

With Laravel Framework

I saved this checkbox to Mysql in one column

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Sun" id="Sun" value="true"> Sun
<input type="checkbox" name="Mon" id="Mon" value="true"> Mon
<input type="checkbox" name="Thu" id="Thu" value="true"> Thu
<input type="checkbox" name="Wed" id="Wed" value="true"> Wed
<input type="checkbox" name="Thur" id="Thur" value="true"> Thur
<input type="checkbox" name="Fri" id="Fri" value="true"> Fri
<input type="checkbox" name="Sat" id="Sat" value="true"> Sat`
```

And I display it in a table.It's displayed like`1,0,1,0,0,0,1`

Here's pic of that output

[image]

But I want to display if the value is equal to `1` like

> `Sun,Thu,Sat`

How can I display like that?

Comment: Change to array and use implode

Comment: I already changed to array but i don't know how to use implode. Can u show me??

Comment: @KhantZin you have save `1,0,1,0,0,0,1` this or image value in database right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ==>

```
$dbvalue = "1,0,1,0,0,0,1"; // value from Database
$values = explode(',', $dbvalue); // Convert String to array 

$days = array("Sun","Mon","Thu","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat"); // take a day array
$output = "";    
for($i=0;$i<count($days);$i++){
   if($values[$i]==1)  // Compare value
       $output .=$days[$i].", "; // append value to $output variable
}
echo trim($output, ", ");  // output = Sun,Thu,Sat
```

Check [Solution](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/e4yj-x9qh) here

Answer (score 0):

When we are working with checkboxes then we can use string value instead of true/false values. Like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Sun" id="Sun" value="Sun"> Sun
<input type="checkbox" name="Mon" id="Mon" value="Mon"> Mon
<input type="checkbox" name="Thu" id="Thu" value="Thu"> Thu
<input type="checkbox" name="Wed" id="Wed" value="Wed"> Wed
<input type="checkbox" name="Thur" id="Thur" value="Thur"> Thur
<input type="checkbox" name="Fri" id="Fri" value="Fri"> Fri
<input type="checkbox" name="Sat" id="Sat" value="Sat"> Sat`
```

And when you will submit the form, then you can see which checkboxes you checked will show you value and other will not show you value.

Check below example and it is working fine.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit;
    }
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Sun" id="Sun" value="Sun"> Sun
    <input type="checkbox" name="Mon" id="Mon" value="Mon"> Mon
    <input type="checkbox" name="Thu" id="Thu" value="Thu"> Thu
    <input type="checkbox" name="Wed" id="Wed" value="Wed"> Wed
    <input type="checkbox" name="Thur" id="Thur" value="Thur"> Thur
    <input type="checkbox" name="Fri" id="Fri" value="Fri"> Fri
    <input type="checkbox" name="Sat" id="Sat" value="Sat"> Sat
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Try this, I think this will help you.

Comment: @KhantZin updated answer with an example. when you select two checkboxes and submit the form then you will get only two checkbox values.